# HTML trying to separate currencys

Tags: php, html

I am sorry if this question is basic. I am new to HTML and PHP, and could use some help.

I am trying to get steam Market prices in USD only, here is the code:

```
<?php
 $Name = "AWP";
 $Skin = "Asiimov";
 $Type = "Field-Tested";

 $string = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/'.$Name.'%20%7C%20'.$Skin.'%20('.$Type.')');
 $attrList = explode('<span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">',$string);
 $N=count($attrList);
 for ($i=1;$i<$N;$i++)
 {
   $prices[$i-1] = explode('</span>',$attrList[$i])[0];
 }
 print_r($prices);
?>
```

Right now it is outputting the prices in the currency that it was set to when it was first posted. Is there a way that I can edit this code to output only in USD or to output only the USD listings?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: how does the data look like?

Comment: like this: Array ( [0] => 38,38€ [1] => CDN$ 58.00 [2] => $42.45 USD [3] => $42.49 USD [4] => $42.50 USD [5] => $42.60 USD [6] => $42.60 USD [7] => $42.60 USD [8] => $42.60 USD [9] => $42.60 USD )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 $Name = "AWP";
 $Skin = "Asiimov";
 $Type = "Field-Tested";

 $string = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/'.$Name.'%20%7C%20'.$Skin.'%20('.$Type.')');
 $attrList = explode('<span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">',$string);
 $N=count($attrList);
 for ($i=1;$i<$N;$i++)
 {
   $prices[$i-1] = explode('</span>',$attrList[$i])[0];
 }

foreach ($prices as $usd) {
    if (strpos($usd, "USD")) {
        echo $usd;
    }
}

?>
```

Not the cleanest code but it does what you want. I just came up with it and so you can just clean it up. Just gave you an idea.

Comment: thank you very much. I will try to clean it up as best as I can. Thank you for you time.